# How do I use __getitem__ and __iter__ and return values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, iterator

I have an object with a dictionary that I want to access via `__getitem__` as well as iterate over (values only, keys don't matter) but am not sure how to do it.

For example:

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jul 22 2009, 15:33:10) 
>>> class Library(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.books = { 'title' : object, 'title2' : object, 'title3' : object, }
...   def __getitem__(self, i):
...     return self.books[i]
... 
>>> library = Library()
>>> library['title']
<type 'object'>
>>> for book in library:
...   print book
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __getitem__
KeyError: 0
>>>
```

How do I tell it to simply return the `object` for each item in the dictionary (the key doesn't matter) ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
def __iter__(self): return self.books.itervalues()
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was something easy but was having the hardest time tracking that down!  Appreciate it.

Comment: Is `return self.books.itervalues()` better than `return iter(self.books.values())` ? I figured it was a dictionary-specific convenience method and was surprised to find that it returns a `dictionary-valueiterator` object, while the other returns a `listiterator`. Same end result, though.

Answer (score 4):

Add this method to Library:

```
def __iter__(self):
  return self.books.itervalues()
```

This delegates iteration to the dict, which has an easy method to iterate values.  Read about the iterator protocol, which consists of `__iter__` (on all iterables) and `next`(`__next__` in 3.x) (only on iterators) methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can return an iterator from your inner data:

```
class Library (object):
  ...
  def __iter__(self):
    return self.books.itervalues()
```

`itervalues()` returns an iterator to the values of the dictionary.

If you want more control, you can make `__iter__` a generator function

```
class Library (object):
  ...
  def __iter__(self):
    for title in self.books:
      yield self.books[title]
```

in this case, this generator yields the exact same as the iterator in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> class Library(object):
...     def __init__(self):                                                     
...             self.books = { 'title' : object, 'title2' : object, 'title3' : object, }
...     def __getitem__(self, i):
...             return self.books[i]
...     def __iter__(self):
...             return self.books.itervalues()
... 
>>> library = Library()
>>> library['title']
<type 'object'>
>>> for book in library:
...     print book
... 
<type 'object'>
<type 'object'>
<type 'object'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`__getitem__(self,key)`, where key is a integer, as your self.books is a dictionary and you can not do `self.books[integer]`

e.g:

```
>>>d = {'a':'sdsdsd','b':'sfsdsd'}
>>d[0]

d[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

the iteration protocol goes like this:

The iterator protocol consists of two methods. The `__iter__()` method, which must return the iterator object and the `next()` method, which returns the next element from a sequence.
previously when `__iter__` method was not defined, it fell back to `__getitem__` by successively calling `__getitem__` with increasing values till it gives index out of range error.