# Python dictionary class, 'KeyError'

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following class which I use to store settings for other objects to access:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

class Settings:                                                                    
    """Singleton settings class"""                                              

    settings = {                                                                   
                   'SectionA': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},                           
                   'SectionB': {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}                            
               }                                                                   

    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.settings[key]                          
    def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.settings[key] = item                    
    def keys(self): return self.settings.keys()                                    

s = Settings()                                                                     
print s.keys()                                                                     
print s['SectionA']                                                                
print s['SectionB']                                                                

for key in s: print s[key]
```

I can't understand why it produces the following output or how to get around it, any help greatly appreciated:

```
foo@bar:~$ python Settings.py
['SectionB', 'SectionA']
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
{'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Settings.py", line 20, in <module>
    for key in s: print s
  File "Settings.py", line 11, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.settings[key]
KeyError: 0
foo@bar:~$
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `for key in s: print key`, not `for key in s: print s`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use \_\_getitem\_\_ and \_\_iter\_\_ and return values from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780571/how-do-i-use-getitem-and-iter-and-return-values-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
class Settings(dict):                                                                    
    """Singleton settings class"""                                              

    settings = {                                                                   
                   'SectionA': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},                           
                   'SectionB': {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}                            
               }                                                                   

    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.settings[key]                          
    def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.settings[key] = item                    
    def keys(self): return self.settings.keys()                                    

s = Settings()                                                                     

for key in s.keys(): 
    print key 
    print s[key]
```

Prints:

```
SectionB
{'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
SectionA
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

**Edit**

Look ma, no `{}.keys()`:

```
class Settings(dict):                                                                    
    """Singleton settings class"""                                              

    settings = {                                                                   
                   'SectionA': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},                           
                   'SectionB': {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}                            
               }                                                                   

    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.settings[key]                          
    def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.settings[key] = item  
    def __iter__(self): return iter(self.settings.keys())               
    def keys(self): return self.settings.keys()      


s = Settings()                                                                                                                                   

for key in s: 
    print key 
    print s[key]
```

Prints same output...

Comment: I agree, this works. However, I'm trying to avoid defining s.keys(). That's my fault for being unclear about what I'm aiming at. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

That's because when you're iterating over the Settings class, it apparently tries to iterate over it by index, like a list. The first index is `0`, which gives a KeyError since it isn't in your dict. You have to define special methods to override the `for key in s` syntax to iterate over your keys.

```
def __iter__(self): return iter(self.settings)
```

Edit: One other thing is that you're using the deprecated old style classes. You should change it to `Settings(object)`

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll give that a try.

Comment: What effect does Settings(object) have?

Comment: This solution ostensibly works, but gives strange 'double' output:`{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
{'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
{'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}`

Comment: @iceaxe, it turns it into a new style class. Basically, a lot of features in modern python only work with new style classes. Look it up for more information.

Comment: This fix my problem when I upgrade from python2 DictMixin to python3.